# How do I configure Webform and CiviCRM for event registration including optional donation

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

When setting up an Event Registration plus optional donation using Drupal's webform/Civi integration module, is it better to set the Contribution Page to Donation or Event Fee?

Comment: You're asking about the Contribution Page, but mention Financial Types.  Please edit the question to clarify which you're referring to?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking because you want each line item to be correctly reported  as such, ie the Donation is a line item with 'donation', and the event fee is 'event fee'. This may be pushing the boundaries for Webform civicrm integration, but searching for 'line item' may help you find other posts about that

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you’re trying to do.

Try set it to Donation. That will make your Contribution level financial type = Donation - but looking at the lineItems within that you should see two lineItems: 1) Financial Type associated with the CiviCRM Event Page for the Event monies and 2) the Financial type Donation for the extras;

That’s how it works for Memberships and top-up optional Donations (for sure - doing that on a number of projects). The Financial Type for the Member $ is what is defined in the Membership Type Config settings.

If this does not work like that for Event registrations - I think it should (it should pull the Financial Type from the Event config); One should be able to have one Contribution with three lineItems - each with a different financial type:

- Member Dues
- Donation
- Event Fees

The first two in combo are working for sure. I’ve not yet tried other combinations.

Keep me posted on what you find.

Comment: Thanks Karin, we in the end did it the other way around as most transactions were event fees with a subset also having donations. We now also use Compucorp's Gift Aid module and that should be looking for line items and not the overall categorisation of the contribution when calculating the contributions that are submittable to HMRC.

Comment: Glad you got things working but - Update! :-) with the latest webform_civicrm release you can now add/configure up to 5 additional line_items on the Contribution entity. And you can make them any Financial Type; you can sell a Calendar and get a Donation as well. You can even just assign a Financial Type that has Sales Tax associated with it - and that works too.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon mentioned you are referring to the financial type of the contribution. A financial type is a way to categorise contributions. Default CiviCRM comes with Donation,Event Fee, Contribution, Campaign contribution. But you are free to define your own financial types.

Which financial types you need depends on the context in which you are using CiviCRM. I know organisations where the Event Fee is good enough but I also know organisations where they make a difference between several events and also want those differences being reflected in their financial reporting.

So to answer the question, I cannot decide for your which one is better for you.